# Image augmentation using Keras when image's pixels and (multi) y-labels saved in two separate DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on CNN using `keras`. I have two separate `DataFrames` which contains pieces of information for an image. One of the DataFrames `imgs` contains the pixels of `137*236`, values ranging from `0-32331` and the image's id column.

```
imgs.head(2)
>>
   image_id       0      1  ...  32330  32331

0  Train_50210  246    253  ...    251    250   
1  Train_50211  250    245  ...    241    244
```

The second DataFrame `train` contains the image's labels and the values of three different classes that each image belongs to. **( For example -> Think of image as living things as plants,fish,humans,animals etc and they can have 0 or more legs,  0 or more eyes and 0 or more nose)**

```
train.head(2)
>>

   image_id   class_1   class_2  class_3    

0   Train_5        15        9         5    
1   Train_1       159        0         0
```

As you can see none of the `DataFrames` are sorted so I thought about sorting both and merging but these contains hundred of thousands of image's data.

**How can I get new distorted images to make the model robust?**

I looked up the `keras` documentations and there was use `ImageDataGenerator(all_the_parameters_here)` from the `keras` to  `.flow()` but no example was given. I know how to use `flow_from_directory` but how can I use `flow()` method in my case?

(Or is there any better alternate approach?)

Comment: This is a job for a custom generator, no doubt. You could try flow, but I think it's inevitable to join the dataframes as you proposed. - In a custom generator, you do the join for each batch (low memory) and apply augmentations with `cv2` or `albumentations`, for instance. With `flow`, you join everything first, then throw it to `flow`.

Comment: @DanielMöller Could you please suggest me how could I because it's just not coming to me , the process. Or you could just point me to any link or tutorial.